# How do you test a function that contains a mocked object instantiated in said function?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest

I'm still green when it comes to testing/mocking and I've been struggling with this today.

In file.py...

```
class FileImporter:
    
    def __init__(self, file=None):
        self.file = file
        
    def process_file(self):
        # process file here...


def import_file(file):
    f = FileImporter(file)
    f.process_file()
    return file
```

Then in test.py...

```
import mock
import pytest

from file import import_file

@mock.patch('file.FileImporter')
def test_import_file(m_importer):
    
    result = import_file('test.csv')
    m_importer.assert_called_with('test.csv')
    m_importer.process_file.assert_called_once()
```

The test above passes the `m_importer.assert_called_with('test.csv')` but fails on `m_importer.process_file.assert_called_once()`. How do I properly handle this? Or is this the wrong way to approach this all together? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you almost have the correct answer, the issue is that when you instantiate a `Mock` object it returns a [new object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.return_value).

> return_value: The value returned when the mock is called. By default
> this is a new Mock (created on first access). See the return_value
> attribute.

That means when the following line is called it returns a new `Mock` object.

```
f = FileImporter(file)
```

The test however is testing the original `Mock` object. To get around this we can set the `return_value` of the Mock object to be itself that way we can test the original patched object.

```
@mock.patch('file.FileImporter')
def test_import_file(m_importer):
    # when instantiated the Mock object will return itself as opposed to a new
    # instance of a Mock
    m_importer.return_value = m_importer
    
    result = import_file('test.csv')
    m_importer.assert_called_with('test.csv')
    m_importer.process_file.assert_called_once()
```

Comment: Awesome... I get it now. Thank you!